# angularjs regex for positive number of fixed length

Tags: angularjs, regex

I'm writing the validations in AngularJS. I've to allow exactly 6 digit positive number (6 digit whole number). I'm using following regex but it isn't working:

```
"pattern": /^\+?[0-9]+$/
```

it is accepting -15 also.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't backslash the first plus sign. In regular expressions a plus sign means that the previous element should be matched one or more times. However, you just want a regular plus, so add a `\` to it.

`/^\+?([1-9][0-9]{5})$/`

If you do more with regular expressions then [RegExr.com](http://regexr.com/) is a great website where you can learn more and test them in real time.

Comment: I don't know how this could allow a dot there when only a plus and digits are specified in the regex. I didn't see you mentioning only exactly 6 digit numbers, check this one then: `/^\+?([1-9][0-9]{5})$/`

Comment: I'm using angularjs for the first time.

Comment: 'society_zip': {
      'title': 'Zip',
      'type': "number",
      "pattern": /^\+?([1-9][0-9]{5})$/              this isn't working :-(

Comment: I don't know how it's checked inside your code, unfortunately. You probably want to extract the string that you need to check and execute a `match` function on it with this pattern. Clearly from RegExr you can see it's working as intended

Answer (score 0):

The first matches any number of digits within your string. The second allows only 6 digits (and not less). So just take the better from both:

```
/^\d{1,6}$/
```

where `\d` is the same like `[0-9]`.

**For example:**

```
    var data ='-15';
    var reg= /^\d{1,6}$/;
    alert(reg.test(data));
    /*
    1. '-15' will prompt false.
    2. '012345' will prompt true.
    3. '' will prompt false.
   */
```

Live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/11Lgvtyy/)

Comment: @Ritika: I update my code, Please check this should work.

Comment: I'm really surprised it is still not working. it is again allowing -15.1004 as input

Comment: So if this is your solution then please accept/vote. Thanks.